# CheckboxList - Tick the checkbox by value from the obj array

Tags: jquery

cblPeriods is the id of the checboxlist control. The below commented line is not working and i am  not sure why it is not working with the chkboxes object. But the line below the commented line works fine when i use the jquery selector.

Please suggest why i cannot work with the chkboxes obj. I have attached the screenshot of the watch window from firebug. The statement

```
$(chkboxes[value=-1]).prop("checked", false);
```

does not yield any object...

```
  $(function () {
        $('#cblPeriods').find(":checkbox").on("click", function () {
            var $obj = $(this);
            var selVal = $obj.val();
            var chkboxes = $('#cblPeriods').find(":checkbox");

            if (selVal == '-1') { //No
                $(chkboxes).not($obj).removeAttr("checked");
            }
            else if (selVal == '0') { //All
                $(chkboxes).not($obj).prop('checked', true);
                //$(chkboxes).find(":checkbox[value=-1]").removeAttr("checked"); //THIS ONE IS NOT WORKING..
                $('#cblPeriods').find(":checkbox[value=-1]").removeAttr("checked");
            }

        });
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JQuery, `find()` will find a child in the DOM that matches your description. Note that

`var chkboxes = $('#cblPeriods').find(":checkbox");`

finds a checkbox that is nested under an element with id, `cblPeriods`.  When you use `$(chkboxes).find(":checkbox[value=-1]")` in your commented line, you are telling JQuery to find a checkbox that is nested under a checkbox nested under `cblPeriods`.  Obviously, this is not what you want.

Perhaps replace it with this:

```
$(chkboxes).filter(":checkbox[value=-1]").removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

is this code ok for u?

```
 var chkboxes = $('#cblPeriods');
 $(chkboxes).find(":checkbox[value=-1]").removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write,

```
$(chkboxes[value=-1]).removeAttr("checked"); //THIS ONE IS NOT WORKING..
```

Comment: Somehow it does not work. -1 value is for "No" checkbox. And it does not remove the ticked state.